# Excel formula to find text and extract a specific length of characters after it

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to extract a SN number from multiple types of Chromebooks with different barcode outputs.  Below is a photo example.

[image: Example Picture of the output I need]

Is it possible to make one formula to extract the serial number from all barcode types?

Here is my request.  I'm wondering if the "=IF" command would work for my needs:

1. First search for "5CD" OR "5CG" and if its found, extract it with the trailing 7 characters. (10 total)
2. If "5CD" OR "5CG" are not found, search for P20 and extract it with the trailing 5 characters. (8 total)
3. If neither are found, keep the cell empty.

Here is a working formula but it only finds one character string.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"",REPT("",99)),MAX(1,SEARCH("5CG",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"",REPT("",99)))-0),10)),"")
```

I know this formula could end up very long.  Thank you for any suggestions. (I'd like to not have to use multiple columns with multiple formulas if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"5CD","5CG","P20"},A1&"5CD5CGP20")),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("P20",A1)),8,10))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Comment: Thank you!!!  This is exactly what I needed.  Your code is so tidy as well.  I really apricate it!

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I tried to upvote as well but it says my votes are hidden since I'm a new user.